# How to use value which is getting changed in an async function and use that value inside that async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, use-state

I am currently working on a ***nextjs*** project and task is to simply *validate* whether user has entered correct details or not during registration. For that purpose i am using *useState* hook from react and changing it's state whenever user clicks on register button.

Now, i have made an ***async*** function which gets invoked whenever user clicks on register button. After that i am checking values and changing states accordingly. If every condition is true then i am sending post request to the server to save that user. This is being done by calling ***addUser*** function. My problem is that even if my conditions are false still code inside the if block is getting executed and i think its because of the fact that states doesn't change immediately and maybe because of async function. My if block is getting old values. Here's a snap of my code.

```
const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Take values from inputs
    const enteredUserName = userNameRef.current.value;
    const enteredMoodleId = moodleIdRef.current.value;
    const enteredEmail = emailRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordRef.current.value;

   

    //Show Error
    regexForMoodleId.test(enteredMoodleId)
      ? setMoodleError(false)
      : setMoodleError(true);

    regexForEmailId.test(enteredEmail)
      ? setEmailError(false)
      : setEmailError(true);

    regexForPassword.test(enteredPassword)
      ? setPasswordError(false)
      : setPasswordError(true);

    if (
      !moodleError &&
      !passwordError &&
      !emailError &&
      checkboxState
    ) {
      //Making spinner visible
      setSpinner(true);

      const response = await addUser(
        enteredUserName,
        enteredMoodleId,
        enteredEmail,
        enteredPassword
      );
      if (response.status === 201) {
        console.log(response.status);

        //Disabling spinner
        setSpinner(false);

        //Redirecting to signin page
        await router.push("/signin");
      } else if (response.status === 302) {
        console.log(response.status);
        //Disabling spinner
        setSpinner(false);
        //Opening error message
        setOpen((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            open: true,
            message: "User already exists! Please signin to continue.",
          };
        });
      } else {
        //Disabling spinner
        setSpinner(false);
        //Opening error message
        setOpen((prevState) => {
          return {
            ...prevState,
            open: true,
            message: "An error has been occurred. Please try again",
          };
        });
      }
    }
  };
```

I want a way in which i can force if block to get new values or wait until values are being updated.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that state is not updating before the rest of the code is executed then do this in class based component:

```
this.setstate({var:new_value}, function(){
//rest of the code
});
```

Function based component equivalent is :

```
const [data, setData] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    doSomething(); // This is be executed when the state changes
}, [data]);

setData(true);
```

Comment: but this will run when component gets loaded for first time. So it will make that request. It there any way to stop that behavior?

Comment: and also this is not working if user is entering everything correct at first instance